# call to AsyncTask method from fragment's onCreateView, fails

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have been trying to implement fragment layout and in one of the fragment classes i am using asynctask.
so far I am unable to call the asynctask method from fragment's oncreateView.
when i run the app its giving error 'unfortunately the app has stopped'

here is my fragment's code

```
package com.example.mohamed.myapplication;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Attributes;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ListView;


import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    // URL Address
    String url = "http://www.androidbegin.com";
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    AsyncTask aTask;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        new Title().execute();

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_frag, container, false);
        return rootView;

    }


    // Title AsyncTask
    private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String title;

//      Context mcontext;
//      public Title(Context c){
//          mcontext=c;
//      }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
//              mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mcontext);
//              mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android Basic JSoup Tutorial");
//              mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
//              mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
//              mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                // Get the html document title
                title = document.title();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Set title into TextView
            TextView txttitle = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.First);
            txttitle.setText(title);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public static FirstFragment newInstance(String text) {

        FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;

    }

}
```

so, what is the right way to call asynctask?

here is my logcat

```
12-01 14:44:40.052    1093-1093/com.example.mohamed.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 49K, 3% free 3755K/3868K, paused 2ms, total 4ms
12-01 14:44:40.056    1093-1093/com.example.mohamed.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 3% free 3973K/4092K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
12-01 14:44:40.064    1093-1093/com.example.mohamed.myapplication I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 6.356MB for 2536932-byte allocation
12-01 14:44:40.072    1093-1103/com.example.mohamed.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 6450K/6572K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
12-01 14:44:40.180    1093-1093/com.example.mohamed.myapplication D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
12-01 14:44:40.180    1093-1093/com.example.mohamed.myapplication D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8a8f1c0, tid 1093
12-01 14:44:40.184    1093-1093/com.example.mohamed.myapplication D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
12-01 14:44:40.184    1093-1093/com.example.mohamed.myapplication D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
12-01 14:44:40.224    1093-1093/com.example.mohamed.myapplication W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-01 14:44:40.224    1093-1093/com.example.mohamed.myapplication E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
12-01 14:44:40.228    1093-1093/com.example.mohamed.myapplication E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
12-01 14:44:40.232    1093-1093/com.example.mohamed.myapplication E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
12-01 14:44:40.232    1093-1093/com.example.mohamed.myapplication E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
12-01 14:44:40.236    1093-1093/com.example.mohamed.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: Where is your code to call the `AsyncTask`? And please post the `logcat`

Comment: @BlazeTama new Title().execute() in onCreateView

Comment: ups sorry my eyes sliped

Comment: Your logcat is missing the actual stacktrace. Many things that can go wrong in your code. Not including the INTERNET permission in your manifest being one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You trying to use `AsyncTask` in `onCreateView` before view created.

Try to call AsyncTask in `onActivityCreated`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
   new Title().execute();
}
```

Comment: the problem was with this line. `mProgressDialog.dismiss();` I just commented that line and called AsyncTask from onActivityCreated. Finally the problem is solved.. Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem lies in this line :

```
TextView txttitle = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.First);
```

Remove that line, and add this line in the `onCreateView` :

```
txttitle = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.First);
```

Make the `txttitle` a global variable.

After that, execute the `AsyncTask` in the `onActivityCreated`

Answer (score 1):

You have a race condition in  your code.  You are starting `Title` from you `onCreateView()` method, before it has returned the `rootView`.  So, if the `AsyncTask` executes and completes *before* the `Fragment` is successfully taken to the running state, you will not get anything from `getView()` in  your `onPostExecute()`.  Also, the code doesn't show when the dialog is started, so you could instead be getting a `NullPointerException` when trying to access `mProgressDialog`.

BTW, your logat is incomplete: it is missing the actual crash stacktrace.  Look for that and it will tell you exactly where your exception is happening.