# Android: Accessing a variable of an inner AsyncTask class but getting it as null in onCreateView of a fragment

Tags: java, android

I have the following codes which get the value of LDR sensor from the cloud. The variable which I am trying to access is `ldrVal` but when I am trying to access that value outside that inner class I am getting it as 0 when I am printing it in a `Toast`. However, when I printed it in a `Runnable` in the inner AsyncTask class, I got the correct non-zero `ldr` value.

```
public class AutomatedControlsFragment extends Fragment {
        public int ldrVal=0;

    @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            new UbidotsConnection().execute();
        }

        public class UbidotsConnection extends AsyncTask{
            private final String API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            private final String UBIDOTS_ID_FOR_LIGHT1 = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            Value[] ldrValues;

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params){
                ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(API_KEY);
                light= apiClient.getVariable(UBIDOTS_ID_FOR_LIGHT1);
                ldrValues= light.getValues();

                ldrVal= (int) ldrValues[0].getValue();
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "ldr value: "+ldrVal,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //toast giving correct value
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "ldr value: "+ldrVal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                return null;
            }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        ldrVal= (int) ldrValues[0].getValue();
    }
        }

     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_automated, container, false);

            //toast giving 0
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "ldr value: "+ldrVal,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      return view; 
    }
}
```

The `Toast` on the `onCreateView` shows `ldr value: 0` while the `Toast` in the AsyncTask shows `ldr value: 90`. I need to access the variable `ldrVal` in `onCreateView` with its latest value.

Comment: Where do you exactly creating an instance of `UbidotsConnection` in your Fragment? Something like `new UbidotsConnection().execute();`?!

Comment: Actually I displayed the `Toast` in Runnable just to see if the correct value of `ldrVal` was being shown. I had to display it in a Runnable thread, otherwise it was throwing an exception

Comment: `new UbidotsConnection().execute();` is in the method `onActivityCreated`

Comment: Nevertheless, you need to execute the task in your activity/fragment then you shall see the value of `ldrVal` changes!

Comment: `onActivityCreated` is called after the Activity's `onCreate()` has completed. It is called after `onCreateView()`, and is mainly used for final initialisations.

Answer (score 2):

I think the value is showing correctly. I do not understand what do you want exactly. However, the values stored in `lrdVal` is fetched in the `doInBackground` method of your `AsyncTask` and then its initialized inside the `AsyncTask`. So the `Toast` is showing the non-zero value while inside your `onCreateView` function you are not getting the value, as the value is not set yet.

You need to check the [Fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) here, which clearly shows that the `onCreateView` is called before `onActivityCreated`. You are calling the `new UbidotsConnection().execute();` method inside `onActivityCreated` which is initializing the value based on the code segment you have shared. So I think the behaviour is correct based on your implementation.

> I'm not sure if either of them is possible though. I have to access
>   `ldrVal` in `onCreateView` in order to perform some operations on it based
>   if it exceeds a certain value.

You cannot get the updated value of `ldrVal` inside your `onCreateView`. Take the actions necessary inside your `doInBackgroud` method or inside the `onPostExecute` function of your `AsyncTask` where your updated value will be available for `ldrVal`.

> I fetched ldrVal in onPostExecute but I still got it as 0 when I
>   displayed variable in a Toast in onCreateView. Here is what I did:
>   @Override protected void onPostExecute(Object o) { ldrVal= (int)
>   ldrValues[0].getValue(); }

Instead of passing a generic `Object o`, you might consider passing the array instead, in your `onPostExecute` function.

```
public class UbidotsConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Value[]> {
    private final String API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    private final String UBIDOTS_ID_FOR_LIGHT1 = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    @Override
    protected Value[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(API_KEY);
        light = apiClient.getVariable(UBIDOTS_ID_FOR_LIGHT1);
        Value[] ldrValues = light.getValues();

        ldrVal = (int) ldrValues[0].getValue();
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "ldr value: "+ldrVal,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //toast giving correct value
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "ldr value: " + ldrVal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return ldrValues;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Value[] values) {
        ldrVal = (int) values[0].getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I mentioned in my comments.

Comment: I see. I was writing an answer and did not see your comments at that time.

Comment: NP, plus one from me though

Comment: Great. Thanks! :)

Comment: So either I have to access the variable inside `onActivityCreated` or I have to create the instance of `Ubidots Connection` in `onCreateView`?

Comment: I'm not sure if either of them is possible though. I have to access `ldrVal` in `onCreateView` in order to perform some operations on it based if it exceeds a certain value.

Comment: Creating the instance of `UbidotsConnection` inside `onCreateView` will give you almost the same result. The primary idea of running an `AsyncTask` is that, this is running in separate thread other than UI thread.

Comment: Thanks.. I was wondering that if I use `AsyncTask` in `onCreateView`, it would have to be used before the view is created and I will come up with errors as described in this ques: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317386/call-to-asynctask-method-from-fragments-oncreateview-fails

Comment: I'll update the value of `ldrVal` in `onPostExecute` rather.. Thanks

Comment: I fetched `ldrVal` in `onPostExecute` but I still got it as 0 when I displayed variable in a `Toast` in `onCreateView`. Here is what I did: `@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            ldrVal= (int) ldrValues[0].getValue();
        }`

Comment: I updated my post with those codes.. You can check the post instead

Comment: Sorry, you need to `return ldrValues;` instead of `null` from `doInBackground` method. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: I checked it.. Still getting `ldrVal` as 0 :/

Comment: Actually I have to access `ldrVal` in `onCreateView` because I have some switches instantiated in that method which are not added in the post for the sake of simplicity for example this line: `        switchAutoLED = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.ledAutoControl);
` Then if the switch is on, I then check if the `ldrVal` is greater than a certain value and then perform some actions based on that.

Comment: I have used a thread in the `onCreateView` to make the API calls(instead of using an inner AsyncTask class) which worked for me